# Difference between addNode and addChild

Tags: c++, widget, cocos2d-x, addchild

I 'm going through cocos2dx 3.0 beta2, the definition of UIWidget is confusing:

```
void Widget::addNode(Node* node, int zOrder, int tag)
void Widget::addChild(Node* child, int zOrder, int tag)
```

What is the deffrence between these two functions?

Comment: just he name of params :)..signature is same for both.

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2dx Rc1, addNode has changed to addInnerNode, so I think it is used for protected node structures for Widget only